# The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Source'. error

Tags: flutter, dart

[image: my error]

I've been trying to play a simple audio file since one day but I couldn't

Answer (score 1):

You cannot play from a `string`. You can play from an `AssetSource` though:

```
oynitici.play(AssetSource('assets/clap1.wav'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
oynitici.setAssets("assets/clap1.wav");
oynitici.play();
```

we need to set music file as the asset first and then we would be able to play that music file. Questioner was skipping setting asset step.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand we need to set music file as the asset first and then we would be able to play that music file. Questioner was skipping setting asset step.